# using .each() .find() and .text() in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, find, each

I've been trying to figure this out for the past few hours and can't get my head round it, so I have the following function:

```
$("SPEECH",currentContext).each(function(){
        var speaker = $("#selectSpeaker").val();
        if($(this).find("SPEAKER").text()===speaker){
            var line = $(this).find("LINE").text();

            $("#speakers").append("<p class='speech'>" + speaker + "</p>" + "<p>" + line + "</p>");
        } 
    });
```

and XML marked up like: http://pastebin.com/GhesMcay

What I am doing is pulling in info such as `LINE` & `SPEECH` through XML, and it is working almost perfectly, its finding the selected `SPEAKER`, finding the `LINE`'s associated with the speaker and outputting them. However I am finding that any `LINE`'s that are in a row in the XML are being placed into 1 long paragraph rather than a new paragraph for each (like I want). By doing this, for the lines that are in a row, no space is placed between the end of one line and the beginning of the next, so the start and end word of lines are being joined together.

From my knowledge I can say this is down to not looking for each individual line, so my thought is that using `.each()` within the variable would solve this, however I cannot seem to get it to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have mentioned is basically correct.  If `$(this).find("LINE")` returns more than one item, then when you call `text()` the text will just get concatenated together.  If you want to do something with each one individually, you can use `each`:

```
var lines = $(this).find("LINE");

lines.each(function(){
   var singleLine = $(this);

   // do something here
});
```

**EDIT**: Another option would be using `map`:

```
var lines = $(this).find("LINE").map(function(){
    return "<p>" + $(this).text() + "</p>";
}).get().join("");

$("#speakers").append("<p class='speech'>" + speaker + "</p>" + lines);
```

Comment: I tried http://pastebin.com/J072RsGa but with no success, don't know if I missed something maybe? Will try the map now!

Comment: as in line/lines? I changed that anyhow.

Comment: No, lines is just what I named the variable.  It shouldn't have had the `text()` at the end.  I updated it.

Comment: haha lack of sleep is making me dumb, I tried that too anyway but it didn't make any difference (not too sure why). In any case, the `map` method works perfectly dude, thanks very much, its been bugging me all day!

Answer (score 0):

.find(...) can potentially return an array of items.  You should map them:

```
$("SPEECH",currentContext).each(function(){
    var speaker = $("#selectSpeaker").val();
    if($(this).find("SPEAKER").text()===speaker){

        // treat this like an array, and return a new paragraph for each line:
        var lines = $.makeArray(
            $(this).find("LINE").map(function() { return "<p>" + $(this).text() + "</p>"; })
        );

        $("#speakers").append("<p class='speech'>" + speaker + "</p>" + lines.join(""));
    } 
});
```

EDIT: Forgot that .map() was the one with the return value...and then you have to call .makeArray.  :(  Unfortunately not as straightforward.

Comment: This won't actually work.  Returning within an each is really just used to break out of the loop or continue.

Comment: unfortunately @JamesMontagne is right amigo, it didn't work, thanks for the input though!